# Error Creating copy of View

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, view, uiviewcontroller

I'm making a copy of an view and I'm trying to set it into my viewController, whenever I try to run the program it always fails at the copy (or reference like I said bear with me). On top of it all the debugger doesn't seem to provide any useful info on what's occurring. Anybody have an idea on what's going on?

`self.accessCities = [[CityViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SwitchView" bundle:nil];`

`UIView *switchView = self.accessCities.view;`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you forgot that `UIView` can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time. So you can't just to take one viewController.view and add it as subview to another. If you want to use viewController's view in another viewController, you can try this:

```
[secondViewController.view addSubview:firstViewController.view];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is storyboard based, you can always drag your curser over the entire UIView and click command+C then command+V